# How to do audio stream processing in Linux(RPi) via C?

Tags: linux, audio, streaming, raspberry-pi, portaudio

Hej
I would like to build an audio effect into a RPi. This effect should be programmed in C. I am not familiar with the software audio interfaces in Linux. The ALSA interface looks very complicated. Port Audio seems to be an alternative.
Any ideas(maybe with a tutorial)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PortAudio seems the best approach. A good tutorial can be found here:

http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/tutorial_start.html

Sometimes the Interface configuration needs to be done manually.

Answer (score 1):

With some work you can also get OpenAL to stream and render audio using c language - then you could perform your processing in that context ...

Node.js is available on RPi which offers audio modules

Comment: Thanks - the last days the openAL side was offline. So far now the download from http://www.openal.org/ seems to work.
Actual I played a little with PortAudio in Linux. It works great. Now I try to compile it with mingw. But this is actual not working.